# wine Direct3D 10 is not supported on this GPU with the current shader backend

Tags: nvidia, wine, playonlinux

Hi i am trying to paly NFS2012 with playonLinxu .
i am geeting error

```
winediag:dxgi_check_d3d10_support Direct3D 10 is not supported on this GPU with the current shader backend
```

[image]

And debug log

```
err:winediag:init_driver_info Invalid GPU override 8086:0a16 specified, ignoring.
fixme:dxgi:dxgi_output_GetDisplayModeList iface 0x13e6a0, format DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, flags 0, mode_count 0x32f3a4, desc (nil) partial stub!
fixme:dxgi:dxgi_output_GetDisplayModeList iface 0x13e6a0, format DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, flags 0, mode_count 0x32f3a4, desc 0x13e1978 partial stub!
fixme:d3d11:D3D11CoreCreateDevice Ignoring feature levels.
fixme:dxgi:dxgi_check_d3d10_support Ignoring adapter type.
fixme:winediag:dxgi_check_d3d10_support Direct3D 10 is not supported on this GPU with the current shader backend.
fixme:system:SystemParametersInfoW Unimplemented action: 59 (SPI_SETSTICKYKEYS)
fixme:system:SystemParametersInfoW Unimplemented action: 53 (SPI_SETTOGGLEKEYS)
fixme:system:SystemParametersInfoW Unimplemented action: 51 (SPI_SETFILTERKEYS)
fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (0x70): stub
fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (0x8c): stub
fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (0x94): stub
fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (0x98): stub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Run `glxinfo | grep GLSL` — the least version you want to see is the *3.30*. Otherwise your driver just doesn't support the GLSL version which wine is using for DX10 implementation.

---

I was also getting the same error, so I decided to investigate it. First we have to find out the code. Grepping over the Wine source shows that the error [resides in `dlls/dxgi/utils.c:448`](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/0806b06f2ba7a690661d6ae417270bdbc7370953/dlls/dxgi/utils.c#L448). Here's relevant part:

```
    hr = wined3d_get_device_caps(factory->wined3d, adapter->ordinal, WINED3D_DEVICE_TYPE_HAL, &caps);
    if (FAILED(hr) || caps.VertexShaderVersion < 4 || caps.PixelShaderVersion < 4)
    {
        FIXME_(winediag)("Direct3D 10 is not supported on this GPU with the current shader backend.\n");
```

So, the error is caused either by `wined3d_get_device_caps` fail, or by too low shader versions. Taking a look [at the implementation in `dlls/wined3d/directx.c:4884`](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/0806b06f2ba7a690661d6ae417270bdbc7370953/dlls/wined3d/directx.c#L4884) for the possible fail reason shows that the `wined3d_get_device_caps` is pretty big function of ≈700 lines, and it have only two *return*s in its body — the fail one is ≈12 lines below the start, and the successful in the end. The fail code looks like

```
    if (adapter_idx >= wined3d->adapter_count)
        return WINED3DERR_INVALIDCALL;
```

Looking at the name of return value `WINED3DERR_INVALIDCALL`, I'd guess that the line here is for the case of a bug — either in Wine or in app. I've a feeling that this is unlikely our case, so let's assume that the function succeeds, return to the `utils.c`, and take a look at the other fail cases, i.e. `caps.VertexShaderVersion < 4 || caps.PixelShaderVersion < 4`.

I haven't work with graphics, so didn't know what're Vertex/Pixel Shader Versions. Searching about it gives an answer, that [it is also referred as «shader model»](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100810075916AAlOCly). Isn't reliable source btw, but the Wikipedia article didn't mention versioning at all, so better than nothing.

Next, searching about shader model gives us [HLSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Level_Shading_Language) article, which fortunately have tables for both Pixel and Vertex shader versions; both tables have `4.0` version, which wine is looking for. One last thing: how could we find whether our GPU driver supports the 4.0 version if it rather implements OpenGL?

Well, it turns out [there's an article about detecting the shader model](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Detecting_the_Shader_Model) for OpenGL, and… there's a comparison of versions for OpenGL and Direct3D! Quoting: `Direct3D Shader Model 4.0 is equivalent to GLSL version 3.30`.

Let's find out whether we got that version:

```
$ glxinfo | grep GLSL
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
```

Well, as you see, it turns out that the driver didn't support the needed version *3.30* ☹ I wish you're lucky, though, if you're reading that, guess you're not.

Answer (score 2):

If your GPU drivers don't support compatibility contexts, you might try to add an registry key to tell Wine to create a core context.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wine\Direct3D]
"MaxVersionGL"=dword:00030002
```

As per [documentation](https://wiki.winehq.org/Useful_Registry_Keys):

> ```
>   |  +->MaxVersionGL
>   |  |   [DWORD Value (REG_DWORD): Choose the maximum GL version to request. Currently defaults to version 1.0.
>   |  |    Set it to 30002 (hexadecimal) or greater to request a core profile context.]
> ```

If running `$ glxinfo | grep GLSL` only reports the OpenGL **ES** shading language version string, you might have been misled. Try `$ glxinfo | grep -e "shading language"` which reports the following for me:

```
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.20
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
```

Comment: and what about the requirements for DX10?

Comment: @JPT: I found [this](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?p=111898&sid=60a77be7c2bd4768458dabf720e660f0#p111898) on WineHQ.org, maybe it's gonna help.